# Prevent POST data manipulation with hash

Tags: php, forms, validation, hash

I am going to protect the data an user enters in a forum using a hash value. I referenced to the following:

```
$hex = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
$split = str_split($hex, 2);
array_unshift($split, '');

$secret = implode('\\x', $split), "\n";
$id = 12345;
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $id, $secret);
```

source: [owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_protect_sensitive_data_in_URL's)

It then states that this hash value can be passed along with the ID in the URL and can be verified like this in a different PHP script:

```
$secret = 'hash';
$id = $_REQUEST["id"]; //in this case the value is 12345
if (hash_equals(hash_hmac('sha256', $id, $secret), $_REQUEST["hash"])) {
  //no tampering detected, proceed with other processing
} else {
  //tampering of data detected
}
```

However, how have they passed the `$secret` variable to the different PHP script? I assume adding it to the url would completely defeat the purpose of the protection.

Comment: Sessions, the answer is sessions.

Comment: You can pass it in the url if you wish - the point is the user can manipulate the ID, but if they do the hash wont match. More importantly, why are you doing this? There is probably a simpler / more robust solution

Comment: You can and should _never_ trust any data you receive from a client. Period.

Comment: I guess I'll go with sessions then. I'm doing this because I want my site to be as secure as possible. I can't think of an easier solution so this really drew my attention.

Comment: Yes, i guessed you where looking to increase security, but of what? How does this help - what could the attacker gain by manipulating the id? probably there is a better option

Comment: Also, to directly answer your question `"(would) adding it to the url would completely defeat the purpose..."` no, because the secret is not known to the attacher, so they cannot generate a new hash to match their new id, and sending the old one would fail, thats the whole point. @arkascha whilst that is a truism, i dont see how that is particularly relevant to this question

Comment: Thanks. But I meant adding the secret to the URL. I'm going to store it in a session because if I add it to the URL an attacker can generate a new hash value with the secret and the desired username.